# MiKTeX and Sphinx : problems on complex TeX output

Tags: errors, pdftex, miktex

I've installed the complete package of **MiKTeX 2.8** because I have to manage the PDF rendering of a TeX file generated by *Sphinx 1.0.4* (Python 2.6) from a ReST source file.

I underline that the HTML output went fine either for Mathematical or graphical part, but when I take the `.tex` file and try to convert via **pdfLaTeX** I catch over 200 recursive errors.

I don't know if the OS is the key, I'm running Sphinx under Windows 7 (no Cygwin) and all works but it generates errors for tables that I haven't.

I'll attach the log file with the main errors extracted.

It refers on a *mathematical research*.

```
(C:\Python26\Scripts\_build\latex\sphinxmanual.cls
Document Class: sphinxmanual
2009/06/02 Document class (Sphinx
manual)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19
v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\size10.clo)))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\utf8.def
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\t1enc.dfu)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\ot1enc.dfu)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\omsenc.dfu)))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\babel\english.ldf
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\babel\babel.def)))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\psnfss\times.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\_build\latex\fncychap.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\tools\longtable.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\_build\latex\sphinx.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.def
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\ts1enc.dfu)))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\fancybox\fancybox.sty
Style option: `fancybox' v1.4
<2010/05/15> (tvz) )
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\titlesec\titlesec.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\_build\latex\tabulary.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\tools\array.sty))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\ams\math\amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath,
use the `' option.
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\ams\math\amstext.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\ams\math\amsgen.sty))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\ams\math\amsbsy.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\ams\math\amsopn.sty))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\makeidx.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\framed\framed.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with
DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline
fix  <2008/02/07> (tvz)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\threeparttable\threeparttable.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\mdwtools\footnote.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\wrapfig\wrapfig.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\ltxmisc\parskip.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg)))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\plain\misc\pdfcolor.tex)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdfescape.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty)))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\oberdiek\hycolor.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\oberdiek\xcolor-patch.sty))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\oberdiek\letltxmacro.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\intcalc.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\ltxmisc\url.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\bitset.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\bigintcalc.sty))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\atbegshi.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver
(autodetected): hpdftex.

(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\oberdiek\atveryend.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\uniquecounter.sty)))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\oberdiek\hypcap.sty))
Writing index file TiberCAD.idx
(C:\Python26\Scripts\_build\latex\TiberCAD.aux)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\base\ts1cmr.fd)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\psnfss\t1ptm.fd)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version
2006.09.02).] ) (C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\oberdiek\refcount.sty)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\generic\oberdiek\gettitlestring.sty))
(C:\Python26\Scripts\_build\latex\TiberCAD.out)
(C:\Python26\Scripts\_build\latex\TiberCAD.out)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in
paragraph at lines 108--108

(C:\Python26\Scripts\MikTex\tex\latex\psnfss\t1phv.fd)
[1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX
/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [2]
(C:\Python26\Scripts\_build\latex\TiberCAD.toc)
Adding blank page after the table of
contents. pdfTeX warning (ext4):
destination with the same identifier
(name{page.i}) has  been already used,
duplicate ignored <to be read again> 
                   \relax  l.108 \tableofcontents    [1]pdfTeX warning
(ext4): destination with the same iden
tifier (name{page.ii}) has been
already used, duplicate ignored <to be
read again> 

! Undefined control sequence. l.1
\chapter{Drift-diffusion simulation of
electrons and holes}

! LaTeX Error: Missing
\begin{document}.

Overfull \hbox (7.80904pt too wide) in
paragraph at lines 12--15
$\OML/cmm/m/it/10 P$

Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in
paragraph at lines 19--20 []

! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.

l.63 \caption  {Solution/Plot
variables}

! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended
by \end{table}.

l.65 \end{table}

! LaTeX Error: Something's
wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX
Companion for explanation. Type  H
<return>  for immediate help.  ...    


l.295 \end{tabulary}

! Missing } inserted. <inserted text> 
                } l.671 \end{tabulary}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link for the LaTeX document produced by Sphinx?

Answer (score 2):

delete your auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.toc`, ...) and run again. If it didn't help, then it looks like a problem in the preamble. Then try

```
\documentclass{...}
... your preamble
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

what happens?